# Edge extension: BackgroundTaskInstance cancels with SystemPolicy reason when DesktopBridge app tries to open WebSocket

Tags: websocket, uwp, desktop-bridge, microsoft-edge-extension

I created an Edge browser extension which uses Native Messaging to a native app running via a Desktop Bridge technology. I used the [SecureInput](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput) as a sample, which contains the Edge extension, UWP host and a Win32 Desktop Bridge app.

I need the Win32 Desktop Bridge app to connect to a web service using HTTP and WebSocket, so I added an `internetClientServer` and a `privateNetworkClientServer` capabilities to the package manifest, beside the already existed `runFullTrust` one.

The Win32 Desktop Bridge app activates just fine, and it is able to connect to the web server using HTTP. But as soon as it tries to open a WebSocket connection, the `BackgroundTaskInstance` on the UWP host receives a cancellation request with a `BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.SystemPolicy` as a reason, and the Desktop Bridge application closes. Unfortunately, the documentation for the `BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.SystemPolicy` does not explain much about true reasons of the cancellation request.

I tried to use two WebSocket classes: the `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` and the `Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket`, with the same result. No fancy code, just regular

```
var socket = new MessageWebSocket();
...
await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://127.0.0.1:9001/myservice"));
```

The same WebSocket service endpoint is available from other WS clients, so I guess there is no server/firewall/antivirus issue here.

I also played with the `CheckNetIsolation` tool, adding loopback exemption for the Edge browser and for the package, with no effect. The HTTP works fine without the loopback exemption.

What may be a true reason of the task cancellation, and what can be a possible way to prevent it?

Comment: Is this specific to Edge Extension, or does it also fail in a regular background task? Also can you clarify: are you making the WebSocket call from your Win32 component or your background task component?

Comment: Stefan, I didn't try it outside the Edge. The WebSocket call was made from Win32 app, but the issue actually was not related with WebSocket at all, see my answer.

Comment: Makes sense. I have seen this one before :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the issue. Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37751226/855109) by [Tom Shane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223763/tom-shane) I stumbled upon, I realized that the `BackgroundTaskCancellationReason.SystemPolicy` tells that the background task is closed by the system to release some system resources, and that in my case it happened because I didn't obtain a deferral in my async event handler. When the event handler yielded without a deferral, the system decided it can shut the task down. Below is a digested version of the code:

```cs
static class Program
{
    static AppServiceConnection connection = null;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread appServiceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        appServiceThread.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }

    static async void ThreadProc()
    {
        try {
            connection = new AppServiceConnection();
            connection.AppServiceName = "...";
            connection.PackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
            connection.RequestReceived += OnRequestReceived;
            connection.ServiceClosed += OnServiceClosed;
            var status = await connection.OpenAsync();
            ....
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
    }

    private static async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var defer = args.GetDeferral();   // <== that was missing, rookie mistake!
        try {
            var msg = ParseMessage(args.Request.Message);
            if (msg.type.Equals("ws")) {
                // this method was truly async
                // and every time it yielded the issue was revealed
                await HandleWsMessage(request, msg); 
            }
            else if (msg.type.Equals("http")) {
                // but this method was actually synchronous despite being marked as "async" 
                // and it never yielded, masking the issue for HTTP client
                await HandleHttpMessage(request, msg);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
        finally {
            defer.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```